# Masonry plugin images over the other ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have read similar questions but can not find nothing to apply to my case.

After an ajax call I append li elements to an ul

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'do_load_gallery.php?load=all'
    }).done(function(result) {

        var data = jQuery.parseJSON(result);

        var count = data.length;

        $.each(data, function (index,val) {

            var $item = $(val);

            var $container = $('#gallery_masonry');#is my ul element
            // initialize
            $container.masonry({
                itemSelector: 'li'
            });
            $container.append( $item ).masonry( 'appended', $item );

            if (!--count) {
                $(window).trigger('resize');
            }
        });
    });
```

Each li element content an image and the width is 25% so I can not know the height of the image. The problem is that the first time I try this code it does not work but if I reload the page or change the windows size masonry applies properly.

Any idea how can I trigger a resize on my window so masonry applies properly? my code above (for resize) does not work

**SOLUTION I FOUND AFTER TERRY OBSERVATION**

```
......
var count = data.length;    
$.each(data, function (index,val) {

                var $items = $(val);
                // initialize
                var $container = $('#gallery_masonry').masonry({element: 'li'});
                $container.append( $items ).masonry( 'appended', $items );
                if (!--count) {
                    $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
                        $container.masonry('layout');
                        $('.mg_wrap').niceScroll();
                    });
                }
            });
```

Comment: The reason why the image dimensions are off at the first run is because the browser is actually loading the images instead of reading them from cache--this means that the natural dimensions and hence the aspect ratio of the images are not available at the first load. You should explore options like image preloading or lazy loading, which contains a callback that will trigger computation of the layout: they actually have an example in the docs http://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html#imagesloaded

Comment: @Terry you should post this as an answer, it's totally correct.

Comment: @VilleKoo Thanks, I'll do that :)

Comment: hey thanks I did not know how to run it after but found a way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To further elaborate on my comment, the reason why the image dimensions appear to be incorrect at the first run is simple: the browser is loading the images from a remote server instead of from its own cache. When the former is happening, the browser actually do not have access to the natural dimensions and hence, the aspect ratio of images.

When this is happening, there is no way that masonry knows how much space the image will take up, and therefore computation of the layout will fail (in the sense that it does not appear to respect the size of the images). To circumvent this, you will have to **preload the images, or wait for the images to be loaded** prior to triggering masonry layout. This works because this ensures that the browser has access to the image dimensions, from which masonry can properly compute the layout.

The masonry docs have a rather good example, using the imagesLoaded plugin: http://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html#imagesloaded